# Reducing Old Browser Support For FontAwesome

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-awesome, truetype

I'm working on a theme for Blogger, and I've chosen to support IE9+.

With Font Awesome, it looks like this:

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.0.3');
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.0.3') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.0.3') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

I don't know much about fonts, but how much of this can I remove? I looked at caniuse.com and it says IE9 has partial support for TTF, and all other browsers support TTF(except for opera mini). Can I not just use TTF?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the following:

[EOT](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eot)
[WOFF](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff)
[TTF](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf)

[It seems like IE9 has partial support of the ttf format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694143/what-is-the-status-of-ttf-support-in-internet-explorer) with the following note:

```
Partial support in IE9 refers to the fonts only working when set to be "installable".
```

If that's unacceptable for you, you can also use EOT or WOFF for IE9 compatibility