# Does IE10 supports OTF?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, opentype

I'm trying to use **OTF in IE 10** but it is not working. I confirmed that TTF is well working in IE 10.

I've already tried to convert OTF to EOT by several service (such as fontssquirrel) but failed. Maybe because my font is not for English.

By the way, I found the [article](https://www.fontfont.com/news/css-opentype-features-for-webfonts) saying that "**(1) IE10 unlocks CSS OpenType features for Webfonts**". Doesn't it indicates "IE supports OTF since version 10?".

However, many people saying that "(2) **All version of IE doesn't support OTF**" when I do googling.

I can't understand difference between those two sentence (1) and (2).

Answer (score 8):

I don't think so, no. Try converting to EOT

You can see a chart of OTF/TTF support in browsers here http://caniuse.com/ttf

More info here: [What is the status of TTF support in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694143/what-is-the-status-of-ttf-support-in-internet-explorer)

I normally convert my fonts using [this online tool](http://onlinefontconverter.com/). Has worked great for me!

Comment: I also used that online tool, but that hasn't worked for me T^T