# Testing TTF on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, truetype

How can I test a TTF file is working on IE browser or not?

I have created a custom font and want to test that logo with a text and file format is ttf.
How do I test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new html/css page with font-family set to your new font and then open it in IE.

The following thread may be of interest: [What is the status of TTF support in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694143/what-is-the-status-of-ttf-support-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Thanks buddy! I thought still easier default setting should be available in IE itself. This should work!

Comment: sure..I tried it then, I can accept only after 12min :)