# Fonts Not Changing on Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, fonts

So I've got this code:

```
@font-face {font-family: "Veger"; src: url('Fonts/Veger(light).ttf'); }
@font-face {font-family: "Kloe"; src: url('Fonts/ff4a_kloe_thin-web.ttf'); }
```

And the fonts aren't displaying on Internet Explorer, which is a problem. I've done some research, and I'm pretty sure the problem is that they need to be .eot, not .ttf. The problem is that I can't seem to change them to .eot, and I'm not sure it's possible. How do you rename them, exactly? I tried the obvious "add .eot to the end," and that just made the file name "Veger(light).eot.ttf... which didn't work.

Comment: and you can see the fonts in `<html_page_dir>/Fonts/Veger(light).ttf)`?

Comment: ... Huh? Never heard of that. You mean can I see the fonts when I open the file? Yes, Veger(light).ttf contains the fonts.

Comment: No, I mean where are the fonts located with respect to the html file? (are they in the same folder as the .html file? or in a subfolder called Fonts? or where exactly?)

Comment: They're in a subfolder called Fonts, yes. The font is changing correctly on every other browser, so I don't think it's a referencing error or anything.

Comment: IE uses .woff files for fonts doesn't it?

Comment: check status of TTF font support for IE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694143/what-is-the-status-of-ttf-support-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Ok, so a quick search (and some information from ochi's link) led me to the conclusion that fonts are complicated... but basically a lot of browsers have different versions with each version only accepting a different file format. And that means one must link to a shit ton of different file formats. My question now is how one changes the file format of a .ttf file, if that's even possible.