# Partial support in IE9+ refers to the fonts only working when set to be "installable" - what's that mean?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to implement an .otf font for a website I am working on with a @font-face rule:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Neris";
  src: url(../fonts/neris/neris-semibold.otf) format("opentype");
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

However, it doesn't work in IE, so I checked it with [Caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf) and it said:

> Partial support in IE9+ refers to the fonts only working when set to
>   be "installable".

What's that mean anyway? Is there anything I can do to make it "installable" or should I give up IE support in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the status of TTF support in Internet Explorer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694143/what-is-the-status-of-ttf-support-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: In answer to your second question (because the above-linked question has the correct answer for the first one), yes, you should give up IE support, by supporting "everything" instead: every currently maintained browser, including IE9, [comes with WOFF support](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff), so in this day and age you don't need five different font formats for webfonts, you just need one. Use that, instead.