# Font ttf file not working with IE

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, fonts, font-face

Im playing around with a site and ttf fonts, but for somereason the font does not want to work in IE.

The css is simple and it works with chrome, but not IE.

```
@font-face 
{
font-family: 'CAROBTN';



src: url('fonts/CAROBTN_.ttf');



}
```

Any ideas?

The simple play site is
[Digi notes](http://www.diginotes.co.uk)

Comment: What IE version are you using? EDIT: It looks like even Microsoft Edge still doesn't support TTF. You need to convert your font to WOFF or EOT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some IE versions don't play nicely with ttf, see here:

[What is the status of TTF support in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694143/what-is-the-status-of-ttf-support-in-internet-explorer)

You will likely need a .eot fallback:

```
@font-face 
{
font-family: 'CAROBTN';

src: url('fonts/CAROBTN_.ttf'),
     url('fonts/CAROBTN_.eot');

}
```

You can convert font files here: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: Thanks, Ill try first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

IE needs `.eot` font format. you can convert your existing `.ttf` font to `.eot` format using [this](http://www.font2web.com/) online converter

Comment: Thanka. Ill try the convert, to convert my ttf and do a fallback.

Comment: Thanks that site worked for one of my fonts. But didn't for but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For IE you need to use .eot font format, so you need to convert your ttf file to eot, with a converter like http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ webfont generator.

For Cross-browser compatibility use all the font formats not just ttf.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Example Font';
    src: url('fonts/Example-font.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Example-font.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
         url('fonts/Example-font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/Example-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/Example-font.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

And for some Chrome font rendering issue, the best solution is to put the svg format at the first position, because in that case the you get the best font rendering result.