# Font falls back to times new roman on IE11

Tags: css, angularjs, sass

I'm trying to add some fonts as assets into my app like this

```
@include font-face('test-Regular', './assets/fonts/test_Regular', null, 'Regular', 'ttf');
@include font-face('test-Bold', './assets/fonts/test_Bold', null, 'Regular', 'ttf');
@include font-face('testCondensed-Bold', './assets/fonts/test_Cond_Bold', null, null, 'ttf');
@include font-face('testCondensed-Regular', './assets/fonts/test_Cond_Regular', null, null, 'ttf');
```

ALL the fonts are working fine on Chrome, FF, but the regular fonts only are NOT working on IE11, with the condensed ones are working as they should be.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the developer tools console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.ttf is not good supported in IE..

Look here for details: [What is the status of TTF support in Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694143/what-is-the-status-of-ttf-support-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Then why are the condensed fonts working and the regular ones are not, also these answers are discussing the issues on IE8,9,10?

Comment: Basically, they only working when fonts are set to be installable. Its a flag, that control which embedding is permitted. Therefore IE is working correctly, however not as expected