# @font-face IE not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, stylesheet, webfonts

When I use this on my style tag the font works just fine with FireFox and Google Chrome And Edge  :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AlArabiyaRegular';
        src :url('template/fonts/ae_AlArabiya.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

but it's not working on IE so I seareched about it and it's looks like I have to use 'woff' and 'eot' in order to make it work with IE so I used this code :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AlArabiyaRegular';
  src: url('template/fonts/ae_AlArabiya.eot');
  src: url('template/fonts/ae_AlArabiya.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('template/fonts/ae_AlArabiya.tff') format('truetype'), 
       url('template/fonts/ae_AlArabiya.svg#webfontg8dbVmxj') format('svg');
}
```

but when I change my style to it's not working even on FireFox

Comment: I think you are missing the format for eot  
src: url('template/fonts/ae_AlArabiya.eot') format('embedded-opentype')
I am not sure it'll work but you can test it.

Comment: Please share your project directory structure.

Comment: @HirenDavda Iam sure about my directory structure because first code was working just fine and all fonts are at the same directory

Comment: take screenshot your project directory and share with us. So we can find out were is the problem. may be your font path is not define properly

Answer (score 0):

Use all the css font family src posibilities:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a `.ttf` works in other browsers but not IE, it's usually a sign that the font hasn't got the "installable bit" set. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694143/what-is-the-status-of-ttf-support-in-internet-explorer) for more info and fixes.